# segmentation fault in c++ SHgetFolder()

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, header-files

When I run this code it works - though not 100% correctly because I can't build folders correctly, so can't open them when I need to.

But when I debug it, I get a segmentation fault when get to "step 2" from "step 1" in MakeFolder.cpp.

Sometimes when I get segmentation fault I can keep continue debugging, sometimes I can't: `gdb.exe stopped working`

I have no idea what is going on. Please help.

MakeFolder.h:

```
#ifndef MAKEFOLDER_H
#define MAKEFOLDER_H

#include <string>

class MakeFolder
{
    public:
        MakeFolder();
        void MakeFile();
        void MakeFile(std::string);
        void MakeFile(std::string,std::string);
        void setFolderWay(std::string);
        void setFolderName(std::string);
        std::string getFolderway();
protected:

private:
    std::string FolderWay;
    std::string FolderName;
};

#endif // MAKEFOLDER_H
```

MakeFolder.cpp:

```
#include "MakeFolder.h"
#include <shlobj.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

/* ... */

    MakeFolder::MakeFolder() /*<=========== STEP 0*/
    {
        char path[MAX_PATH];
        SHGetFolderPath(NULL,
        CSIDL_DESKTOPDIRECTORY | CSIDL_FLAG_CREATE,
        NULL,
        0,
        path);  /*<====== STEP 1*/                              
        setFolderWay(std::string(path));  /*<========== STEP 2*/
        setFolderName("Name");
     }

/* ... */

void MakeFolder::setFolderWay(std::string F_way)
{
    FolderWay=F_way;
}

void MakeFolder::setFolderName(std::string F_name)
{
   FolderName=F_name;
}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string> 

/* ... */

#include"MAKEFOLDER.h"

/* ... */

int main()
{

    MakeFolder *flder= new MakeFolder;//OR =new MakeFolder(); 
                  /*          /*OR MakeFolder Flder; //OR MakeFolder Flder() 
                   *           MakeFolder *flder=&Flder//OR =Flder etc. */
                   *           //I tried many things
                   */
```

When I look into setFolderWay() after segmentation fault it says :

```
The program being debugged was signaled while in a function called from GDB.
GDB has restored the context to what it was before the call.
To change this behavior use "set unwindonsignal off". 
Evaluation of the expression containing the function
(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, 
std::allocator<char> >::c_str() const) will be abandoned.
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x6fe6d9ac in 
libstdc++-6!_ZNKSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEE7_M_dataEv 
() from C:\MinGW\bin\libstdc++-6.dll
```

Comment: Try checking whether call to `SHGetFolderPath()` succeeds.

Comment: _Sometimes when I get segmantation fault I can keep continue debugging,"_ What debugging are you doing, exactly? I don't see a backtrace here, strangely, or any indication of variables' values, or any actual useful employment of a debugger.

Comment: when I debug, debugger gets "step 0" then jump to "step 1" and then jump to "step 2" then "SEGMENTATION FAULT" is that meaning calling SHGetFolderPath() fails ?

Comment: @MKS Why don't you check and tell us, if `SHGetFolderPath()` fails?It returns `HRESULT`

Comment: when I check the returning value (I mean "path") it has correct way to desktop at beginning but it has many garbage after that  "C:\\Users\\MKS\\Desktop\000\b'\032\001\000\000\032\001\000\000\000\000\200\000\000\000\000'\032\....

Comment: @MKS It is correctly terminated by `\0`

Comment: yes , do you have any idea what cause that?

Comment: @MKS so it seems call to `SHGetFolderPath()` was ok, and the problem is somewhere else.Maybe in some portion of code you did not show.Can you reproduce the problem at your end with the above code itself, or you have some different code?

Comment: @MKS Wait..What is `KlasorOlustur` and how are you able to call `MakeFolder::setFolderWay()` without an instance of `MakeFolder`?

Comment: @Gaurav have 6 different headers many other codes... But what the main function does first is calling that constructer

Comment: @MKS But to call `MakeFolder::setFolderWay()`, you need an instance of `MakeFolder`.Don't you think so?

Comment: dont mind KlasorOlustur I forgot to translate that editted now.  After calling constructer second thing I do is creating a folder on desktop by MakeFolder obj.

Comment: why would I need an instance it is function of same class ?